# Is there a way to pay by amount on stripe using JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, stripe-payments

Is there a way to initiate a stripe payment from the front end using stripe and js (I'm currently using Vue) without specifying products on the stripe dashboard. I would like something where I just the total amount and a payment page of that total amount gets charged to the dummy account.
totalAmount = $100,
description: 'Donation details',

function charge() {
--- initiates a payment of 100 USD ----
}
I was wondering if there is a package that could help me out with this.
I'm new to front end development and wanted to check this out, feels like the answer is simple but I can't seem to find it.
Thanks

Comment: asking for packages, libraries etc is off topic - have you checked the fine Stripe documentation for answers? Note: the fact that you're using vuejs is irrelevant to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, I tried their documentation but so far all I could find was initiating payment after setting up products in my stripe dashboard, which I'm not trying to achieve. I wish to initiate payments where I just send the amount. The other method I've found is payment intent but for that I've only found ways to make it work with back-end

Comment: `I've only found ways to make it work with back-end` - then thats your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Checkout Session (hosted payment page by Stripe), you can:

1. Ask user for the donation amount at client/frontend
2. Send the donation amount to backend to create a Checkout Session with ad-hoc `price_data` instead of `price` under `line_items`: https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices#ad-hoc-prices
3. Redirect user to the Checkout Session URL

Example in Step 2,

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          unit_amount: 10000,
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'Donation',
          },
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
    cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
```

Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout

Please note that client-only Checkout integration doesn't support ad-hoc price using `price_data` param, so it's not possible to do with client/frontend only. Ad-hoc price is only supported in server/backend Checkout integration.

---

Alternatively, you can create a price with pay-what-you-want in Dashboard, i.e. amount entered by customer in Checkout Session page:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pay-what-you-want

After that, client-only Checkout integration provided by community library, vue-stripe with pay-what-you-want price ID can be used:
https://docs.vuestripe.com/vue-stripe/stripe-checkout/one-time-payment

Comment: This question was asked and posted here. i mean it's duplicated question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893286/is-there-a-way-to-pay-by-amount-on-stripe-using-js

Comment: Isn't the link this page?